# How Hadoop manage load balancing

Tags: hadoop, load-balancing

I have just started working on Hadoop.
I want to know how hadoop manage load balancing.

If I have 5Nodes in one cluster then How hadoop ensure that each node have equal work load?
Is there any algorithm used by Hadoop for load balancing?

Could you please help me to learn Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean YARN, the ResourceManager, not HDFS, the filesystem.

YARN does not ensure nor guarantee equal processing.

In terms of MapReduce, if your data is heavily skewed towards particular key pairs, then one process of one node will be the bottleneck for the job.

If you instead meant HDFS, then there's literally something called the HDFS Rebalancer, but that's to ensure your data is fairly spread within the cluster so that the jobs can become better distributed themselves in terms of "data locality". However, that still won't help the skewness of the data.